# JS: Adding text inputs dynamically not working

Tags: javascript, input, dynamic

I have looked at all versions of this simple script and I cannot get it to work.

Button adds fields, I check the source code as I click the button and it adds the correct fields with the correct name= but when I Submit, no info is transferred from the dynamically added fields.

```js
var count = 2;
function addLine() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
 var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
 var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
 var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
 cell1.setAttribute("class", "odd");
 cell2.setAttribute("class", "odd");
 cell3.setAttribute("class", "odd");
 cell4.setAttribute("class", "odd");
 cell5.setAttribute("class", "odd");
 var input1 = document.createElement('INPUT');
 input1.setAttribute("type", "text");
 input1.setAttribute("name", "input" + count + "d1");
 input1.setAttribute("class", "whtext");
 cell1.appendChild(input1);
 cell2.innerHTML = "<input class='whtext' name='input" + count + "d2' type='text'>";
 cell3.innerHTML = "<input class='whtext' name='input" + count + "d3' type='text'>";
 cell4.innerHTML = "<input class='whtext' name='input" + count + "d4' type='text'>";
 cell5.innerHTML = "<input class='whtext' name='input" + count + "d5' type='text'>";
 document.getElementById("counter").value = count;
 count++;
}
```

As you can see, I have two different versions I've tried, with appendChild and just adding into the innerHTML. I am new-ish to JS so this has me stumped.

I've run the var_dump($_POST); and none of the JS added fields show up.

Comment: The best thing you can do to start with is to separate it into functions like createCell(), createInput(). That way your code will be more organized and easy to change, this is not the best way, I can provide an answer to your problem but I would not be really helping you.

Comment: I suspect the input1.setAttribute("name",... ) is not working as ive seen cases where browsers wont let you set the name using setAttribute.. have u tried innerHTML instead of DOM methods as a test?

also what browser?

Comment: We need the HTML code coming with it !

Comment: Also are u sure ur table is wrapped in a <form> ?

Comment: I've tried the innerHTML way as shown below the DOM method. Neither worked.

I am using Chrome browser.

And yes, the table is existing that is just being added to with the script.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming this HTML:**

```
<form>
  <input type="hidden" id="counter">
  <table id="myTable">
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**Try this JS:**

```
var count = 2;

function addLine() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(-1);
  var noOfCols = 4;
  for (var i = 0; i < noOfCols; i++) {
    var cell = row.insertCell(i);
    cell.setAttribute("class", "odd");
    cell.innerHTML = "<input class='whtext' name='input" + count + "d" + (i + 1) + "' type='text'>";
  }

  document.getElementById("counter").value = count;
  count++;
}

addLine();
```

**jsfiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/3tbekvc1/
*(inspect the network after submit to verify that the form vars are getting sent)*

Comment: Sorry, but the script works fine. I have it add the fields I want, everything, and it adds the correct name to the input fields added so they are all individually named, but when I go to the submitted page, the data entered does not show up.

Comment: Also are u sure ur table is wrapped in a <form> ?

Comment: Yes, I have one field of inputs that are in the same table as this script that are coded into the HTML, and they send data over just fine. Its the javascript added input fields that dont.

Comment: if ur inputs have a valid name and are not disabled,and they are within a FORM and you are doing a form submit, there is no way that they wont get sent. Your error is likely somewhere else.  You need to provide your HTML code. Else it is not possible to take this further. Are you sure you're not missing anything silly ?

Comment: http://www.gbcab.com/doors/blank2.php this is the website link to this form. It is a door order form for my company. If you type in the first value for "Type" "Qty" "Width" "Height" "Notes", and click submit, they will transfer to the next page. If you Click the + and add another line, and enter data, you can see in the debug console, it adds the inputs with the appropriate name, inputXd1, inputXd2, etc.. but when you submit, they do not transfer